# Textbook Proposition on Quotient of Real Analytic Functions

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-functions

> Let $f$ and $g$ be real analytic functions, both of which are defined on an open interval $I$. Assume that $g$ does not vanish on $I$. Then the function
>
> \begin{align*}
>   h(x) &= \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \\
> \end{align*}
>
> is real analytic on $I$. Moreover, if $I$ is centered at the point $c$ and if:
>
> \begin{align*}
>   f(x) &= \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_j (x - c)^j \\
>   g(x) &= \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty b_j (x - c)^j \\
> \end{align*}
>
> then the power series expansion of $h$ about $c$ may be obtained by formal long division of the latter series into the former. That is, the zeroeth coefficient $c_0$ is $a_0/b_0$ and the order one coefficient is
>
> \begin{align*}
>   c_1 &= \frac{1}{b_0} \left( a_1 - \frac{a_0 b_1}{b_0} \right) \\
> \end{align*}

Letting $w = x-c$, here is my work for calculating $c_1$:

\begin{align*}
  \left( \frac{a_0}{b_0} + c_1 w \right) \left( b_0 + b_1 w \right) = a_0 + a_1 w \\
  a_0 + \frac{a_0 b_1 w}{b_0} + b_0 c_1 w + b_1 c_1 w^2 - a_0 - a_1 w = 0 \\
  \frac{a_0 b_1}{b_0} + b_0 c_1 + b_1 c_1 w - a_1 = 0 \\
  c_1 = \frac{1}{b_0 + b_1 w} \left( a_1 - \frac{a_0 b_1}{b_0} \right) \\
\end{align*}

Can someone explain the differing $b_1 w$ term in my answer?

Comment: I think it's easier to work with products. Just solve $(\sum_j c_j (x-c)^j)(\sum_j b_j(x-c)^j) = \sum_j a_j(x-c)^j$ by expanding out the left hand side.

Comment: Re. above comment: I think you can substitute say $w$ for $x-c$ since you want expansion around $x=c.$